shellspec kcov integration not reporting code coverage
I have a problem getting code coverage to work with shellspec
I have a directory at $HOME/work/hello
It's contents are as followed:
hello
  |______  hello.sh
  |______  spec
             |______  hello_spec.sh

hello.sh looks like this:
echo hello
spec/hello_spec.sh looks like this:
Describe 'spec for my test'
   It 'says hello'
   When call ./hello.sh
      The output should eq "hello"
   End
End

In $HOME/work/hello I then execute
shellspec --shell bash -f d --kcov --kcov-options="--include-pattern=$(pwd)/hello.sh"
To my understanding, this launches shellspec with bash selected as my shell, and using a formatter aliased by d. --kcov then enables kcov integration (which I have installed), and kcov-options should then pass --include-pattern to point at my script hello.sh
The output shows that the test has executed and passed, yet kcov reports 0% coverage.
14:24:01 ❯ shellspec --shell bash -f d --kcov --kcov-options="--include-pattern=hello.sh"
Running: /usr/bin/bash [bash 5.1.16(1)-release]

spec for my test
  says hello

Finished in 0.12 seconds (user 0.10 seconds, sys 0.02 seconds)
1 example, 0 failures

Code covered: 0.00%, Executed lines: 0, Instrumented lines: 1

When I open $HOME/work/hello/coverage/index.html I can see that kcov succesfully recognized my hello.sh file.
It reads the line echo hello, but it reports no coverage.
What am I doing wrong?
I have tried the pattern without $(PWD), and I have also tried When call $(PWD)/hello.sh to ensure the paths exactly match.
For reference, when I run kcov coverage hello.sh kcov reports 100% coverage just fine.
